# How access a deployed website with ZEIT Now?

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting, vercel

I was trying to host my website with ZEIT - Now and the deployment was succesfull, but I can't access it with my url (https://site-bmwuvcgqf.now.sh) because he only downloads my source code and doesn't show the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now v2 requires a `now.json` file to tell it to use a PHP Builder

https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/official-builders/php-now-php/

Add one to your project and deploy again